# How to create an upper triangular matrix where elements in each row increase in a sequence?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried the below code:

```
arr = np.triu(np.ones((5, 5)))
arr[arr > 1] = np.arange(1, np.sum(arr > 1) + 1)
print(arr)
```

i expect
for ex n=5 that would be

```
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `triu` of an array of ones, and calculate the [cumulative sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) along the `1` axis:

```
import numpy as np

n=5
arr = np.cumsum(
           np.triu(
             np.ones((n, n))
           ), axis=1)

print(arr)
```

Gives:

```
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VcyxCoAwDATQPV@RsYEiiDj2Y4oIdkga0hb062txUW@7d3B61SPL0ntizVZRGuuFsaAogIQVohmG0aatcWnsAN8MrZbazx7NshfnxKMQfUfyGM9UwkwAakmqG/fU@w0)

Comment: Thank you so much for your invaluable help! Your guidance and support made a significant difference, and I'm truly grateful for your time and effort. Your expertise and willingness to assist have been instrumental in resolving my concerns. Once again, thank you for your kindness and assistance.